# Make existing Android app freemium, unfair to existing customers

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Does anyone know if it is possible to take an existing Android app (Paid) with ~500 paying customers and convert to a Freemium model without causing the members to pay again when upgrading from within the store? **Yes/No answer with evidence sought**

The only way I could think of doing this was to create a new app in the store, halting development on the existing app and turning it into a key-app of sorts that behaves like an alternate unlock for the new Freemium app; e.g.

```
if (existing app is installed || purchase exists in in app billing receipts) {
     // Unlock premium value
}
```

Existing users would then be directed at the new app to download and install, but would be required to keep the key app (first app) installed to avoid having to pay?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are few ways to do it.
First of all the main challenge is to determine if user already paid for app. When you will know it you will be able to put some `if` to your `Application` class which will turn on premium option for users who already paid for app. Example:

```
public class MySingltone extends Application {
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
 if(alreadyPaid)
   //Turn on premium stuff
 }
}
```

Ok. Now about ways to determine if user already paid for your app:

1. Maybe you have some `SharedPreferences` or settings which you create after user installs the app, so you will be able to check if it exist -> app was installed before-> user paid for it. Just add some flag after this check, because on the second launch all users will be "old users". So make this check only once per user.
2. If you don't have such things you can put to Google Play update for your app,
   which will just put to `SharedPreferences` `boolean
   wasInstalled=true`. So after everybody update their apps, you will
   be able to determine old users by `if(isFirstLaunch==true)`. Just
   don't forget to make one more update which will remove adding
   `boolean wasInstalled=true` before making your app freemium.
3. You can copy emails of all users who bought your app (from Google Play walt) to file. And then in `if(alreadyPaid)` check if current device email exist in this list->user bought app. (you will need to add permission to manifest for getting users email)

Comment: I like your idea of copying the email addresses of users who have already paid and checking those, only because that will ensure that even users who purchased then uninstalled will always be able to access premium content for free if they re-install the app; the other suggestions depend on the users who have already paid having the app currently installed for the flagging to work. I will give it a shot and report back.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be possible to get the purchasers email addresses from within the merchant account; I know it used to be possible in the past but it seems they have for privacy reasons changed this after the outcry. I suppose I could patch the existing client to collect user's current google account details logged onto the phone and send those to a server for collection and inclusion into a premium list in the future.

Comment: Yes I checked it too, Google changed the merchant account( I think your idea with collecting emails and sending them to server is good, though it is very similar to flagging, but flagging doesn't need permission in manifest...

Comment: That is true, but I don't think the flagging option will work for users who have paid but don't have the app installed will it? Actually in hind sight neither of these options will allow that, leaving as far as I can tell only my earlier suggestion of turning the existing app into a key-app and releasing a freemium partner version which checks for the key apps existence OR the existence of the in app billing purchase before unlocking features.

Comment: Flagging option will work only if user opened the app at least one time after you updated it with flagging option. "Turning the existing app into a key-app" - I used this option for one of my apps, and it worked pretty good, the disadvantage is that it can be confused to old users, that now the need to download new app, and existing app is only the key.

Comment: Thanks Alon, yeah my concern with going with the convert to key model is that we loose all of our ratings and comments which are largely good reviews :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that as long as you abstract the state of your app from the purchasing state of any consumable, subscription or in general any in-app product you may have.
Let's get through with an example.

Let's say my app shows pictures of fruits and free customers can see pears and bananas, whereas freemium can additionally see strawberries and lemons on top. Since you have to different ways of recognising users as premium (existing users who paid already + new users who buy through in-app products, you need a system/state which is agnostic to that).

**1. Flagging premium state**

Simplest idea would be to have a flag isPro/proState saved on your disk (SharedPreferences, SQLiteDatabase, other) but that would make it easy for users with rooted devices to access your premium features. Solutions are multiple here and it's more up to you, but if you already have any central place or server where your users live, there's not better place to do so for persisting users' pro state. However if you are not using SSL you may want to do some hashing on top to communicate between server and client.
Ultimately and if that's not crucial to you don't bother much. First, you won't get many fake pros and second you can be happy that they take the time to try to "crack" your premium accounts and spread the word about how cool your strawberries and lemons are.

**2. Converting existing users to a premium state**

If I didn't get it wrong, your existing users already paid for your app, I guess that means you want to set them as premium users right away. Here it's all about tracking users' current version, there are some ways to do that:

(listed from most to least ideal)

- If you already keep record of users' current version either on your server or persist it locally you have it done. Just check last and current version and update user's premium state. Note: If you are not doing that yet it might be a good moment to think about it. Persisting users' current version brings a lot of benefits (analytics, new feature highlight, migrations, etc) and takes away a lot of hassle from you (support, the problem you are facing, etc).
- If you don't, but you are using persistence in SQLite you could use update the version of your database model and make use of [onUpgrade method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) to know if a given user comes from the old version or if it's a new user, although that one is a bit hacky to my eyes.
- As a last bullet, in general users leave traces when they use your app, if you have any way to resolve that (check for existing database, check for pre-set keys on SharedPreferences, cookies, etc) you could know if a user comes from an older version or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment there is no central user database or information, the users are only identified as the accounts who have purchased the application from the Google Play store. The google play store gives me statistics around what percentage of my users are using which version but I don't believe that it allows me to identify individual user versions. I like the onUpgrade idea, but unforunately I am concerned that those approaches won't grant premium access to people who have purchased the app, but don't currently have it installed.

Comment: Correct, if there's no central server/system identifying your users nor anywhere on your app to relate which users are the ones who paid, nor are you registering the account which users paid with, there isn't a proper way (as far as I can think of) to do what you want. I'd try something that checks your local state (like onUpgrade) + contact the rest of your users to provide with a way to get premium if they already bought your app (they could provide some proof of their purchase). Fortunately, you won't have many of them since they won't be very active users of the app.